# String "multiplication" or distribution

Tags: python-2.7

I thought there was a built in function for this but I can't find it in the documentation.

I am trying to do the following simply as a shortcut: (where `abcd` are all strings)

```
stringlist = [a,b] * [c,d]
```

expected result

```
stringlist = [ac,ad,bc,bd]
```

I may have been confusing this with `zip([a,b],[c,d])` which obviously does something totally different.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [`product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

```
from itertools import product
[x + y for x, y in product([a, b], [c, d])]
```

In case of strings you can simply do

```
[x + y for x, y in product("ab", "cd")]
```

Comment: Don't you mean `x + y`? `<str> * <str>` is nonsensical.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist yep. fixed it!

Comment: this worked, I guess it's not that much cleaner than the list comprehension `[x + y for x in [a,b] for y in [c,d]]`, oh well